# Restructure Json data to organized form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I need to restructure this json file :

```
[
 {
   "Id":1,
   "userId":"dd1789f1-bb28-4f2c-975a-bad0e3d127cd",
   "email":"lalaland@gmail.com",
   "projName":"1",
   "taskName":"2",
   "startDate":"2017-01-22",
   "endDate":"2017-01-28",
   "hr_Sun":"0.00",
   "hr_Mon":"0.00",
   "hr_Tue":"0.00",
   "hr_Wed":"0.00",
   "hr_Thu":"0.00",
   "hr_Fri":"0.00",
   "hr_Sat":"0.00",
   "total_hr":"0.00"
 },
 {
   "Id":2,
   "userId":"dd1789f1-bb28-4f2c-975a-bad0e3d127cd",
   "email":"lalaland@gmail.com",
   "projName":"1",
   "taskName":"3",
   "startDate":"2017-01-22",
   "endDate":"2017-01-28",
   "hr_Sun":"0.00",
   "hr_Mon":"0.00",
   "hr_Tue":"0.00",
   "hr_Wed":"0.00",
   "hr_Thu":"0.00",
   "hr_Fri":"0.00",
   "hr_Sat":"0.00",
   "total_hr":"0.00"
 },
 {
   "Id":3,
   "userId":"dd1789f1-bb28-4f2c-975a-bad0e3d127cd",
   "email":"lalaland@gmail.com",
   "projName":"2",
   "taskName":"3",
   "startDate":"2017-01-22",
   "endDate":"2017-01-28",
   "hr_Sun":"0.00",
   "hr_Mon":"0.00",
   "hr_Tue":"0.00",
   "hr_Wed":"0.00",
   "hr_Thu":"0.00",
   "hr_Fri":"0.00",
   "hr_Sat":"0.00",
   "total_hr":"0.00"
 }
]
```

My final result should be like this:

```
{
  "projects":[
   {
   "projName":"1",
   "task_data":[
    {
     "taskName":"2",
     "task_detail_data":[
       {
        "h_sun":"0.00",
        "h_mon":"0.00",
        "h_tue":"0.00",
        "h_wed":"0.00",
        "h_thu":"0.00",
        "h_fri":"0.00",
        "h_sat":"0.00"
       }
      ]
    },
    {
     "taskName":"3",
     "task_detail_data":[
       {
        "h_sun":"0.00",
        "h_mon":"0.00",
        "h_tue":"0.00",
        "h_wed":"0.00",
        "h_thu":"0.00",
        "h_fri":"0.00",
        "h_sat":"0.00"
       }
      ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "projName":"2",
   "task_data":[
    {
     "taskName":"3",
     "task_detail_data":[
       {
        "h_sun":"0.00",
        "h_mon":"0.00",
        "h_tue":"0.00",
        "h_wed":"0.00",
        "h_thu":"0.00",
        "h_fri":"0.00",
        "h_sat":"0.00"
       }
      ]
    }
   ]
  }
```

so, task with same project will be keep inside the same project array. however, in my current code, it keep on returning different array even with same id.

```
var project_data = [];
var proName = "";
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    var startDate = arr[i].startDate;
    var endDate = arr[i].endDate;
    var week_data = { startDate, endDate };

    var projName = arr[i].projName;

    if (proName != projName) {
        //create new task
        proName = arr[i].projName;
       // alert(projName);

        var taskName = arr[i].taskName;

        var task_data = [];
        var task_detail_data = [];

        var h_sun = arr[i].hr_Sun;
        var h_mon = arr[i].hr_Mon;
        var h_tue = arr[i].hr_Tue;
        var h_wed = arr[i].hr_Wed;
        var h_thu = arr[i].hr_Thu;
        var h_fri = arr[i].hr_Fri;
        var h_sat = arr[i].hr_Sat;

        task_detail_data.push({ h_sun, h_mon, h_tue, h_wed, h_thu, h_fri, h_sat });
        task_data.push({ taskName, task_detail_data });
    }
    else {
        var taskName = arr[i].taskName;

        var task_data = [];
        var task_detail_data = [];

        var h_sun = arr[i].hr_Sun;
        var h_mon = arr[i].hr_Mon;
        var h_tue = arr[i].hr_Tue;
        var h_wed = arr[i].hr_Wed;
        var h_thu = arr[i].hr_Thu;
        var h_fri = arr[i].hr_Fri;
        var h_sat = arr[i].hr_Sat;

        task_detail_data.push({ h_sun, h_mon, h_tue, h_wed, h_thu, h_fri, h_sat });
        task_data.push({ taskName, task_detail_data });

    }
    project_data.push({ projName, task_data }); 
}
var output = { projects: project_data };
var json = JSON.stringify(output);
$('#output').html(json);
```

}

Guys, please do help me to fix this. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```js
var arr = [
             {
                     "Id": 1,
                     "userId": "dd1789f1-bb28-4f2c-975a-bad0e3d127cd",
                     "email": "lalaland@gmail.com",
                     "projName": "1",
                     "taskName": "2",
                     "startDate": "2017-01-22",
                     "endDate": "2017-01-28",
                     "hr_Sun": "0.00",
                     "hr_Mon": "0.00",
                     "hr_Tue": "0.00",
                     "hr_Wed": "0.00",
                     "hr_Thu": "0.00",
                     "hr_Fri": "0.00",
                     "hr_Sat": "0.00",
                     "total_hr": "0.00"
                 },
                 {
                     "Id": 2,
                     "userId": "dd1789f1-bb28-4f2c-975a-bad0e3d127cd",
                     "email": "lalaland@gmail.com",
                     "projName": "1",
                     "taskName": "3",
                     "startDate": "2017-01-22",
                     "endDate": "2017-01-28",
                     "hr_Sun": "0.00",
                     "hr_Mon": "0.00",
                     "hr_Tue": "0.00",
                     "hr_Wed": "0.00",
                     "hr_Thu": "0.00",
                     "hr_Fri": "0.00",
                     "hr_Sat": "0.00",
                     "total_hr": "0.00"
                 },
                 {
                     "Id": 3,
                     "userId": "dd1789f1-bb28-4f2c-975a-bad0e3d127cd",
                     "email": "lalaland@gmail.com",
                     "projName": "2",
                     "taskName": "3",
                     "startDate": "2017-01-22",
                     "endDate": "2017-01-28",
                     "hr_Sun": "0.00",
                     "hr_Mon": "0.00",
                     "hr_Tue": "0.00",
                     "hr_Wed": "0.00",
                     "hr_Thu": "0.00",
                     "hr_Fri": "0.00",
                     "hr_Sat": "0.00",
                     "total_hr": "0.00"
                 }
    ];

    var project_data = [];
    var proName = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var startDate = arr[i].startDate;
        var endDate = arr[i].endDate;
        var week_data = { "startDate": startDate, "endDate": endDate };

        var projName = arr[i].projName;

        if (proName != projName) {
            //create new task
            proName = arr[i].projName;
            // alert(projName);

            var taskName = arr[i].taskName;

            var task_data = [];
            var task_detail_data = [];

            var h_sun = arr[i].hr_Sun;
            var h_mon = arr[i].hr_Mon;
            var h_tue = arr[i].hr_Tue;
            var h_wed = arr[i].hr_Wed;
            var h_thu = arr[i].hr_Thu;
            var h_fri = arr[i].hr_Fri;
            var h_sat = arr[i].hr_Sat;

            task_detail_data.push({ "h_sun": h_sun, "h_mon": h_mon, "h_tue": h_tue, "h_wed": h_wed, "h_thu": h_thu, "h_fri": h_fri, "h_sat": h_sat });
            task_data.push({ "taskName": taskName, "task_detail_data": task_detail_data });

            project_data.push({ "projName": projName, "task_data": task_data });
        }
        else {
            var taskName = arr[i].taskName;

            var task_data = [];
            var task_detail_data = [];

            var h_sun = arr[i].hr_Sun;
            var h_mon = arr[i].hr_Mon;
            var h_tue = arr[i].hr_Tue;
            var h_wed = arr[i].hr_Wed;
            var h_thu = arr[i].hr_Thu;
            var h_fri = arr[i].hr_Fri;
            var h_sat = arr[i].hr_Sat;

            task_detail_data.push({ "h_sun": h_sun, "h_mon": h_mon, "h_tue": h_tue, "h_wed": h_wed, "h_thu": h_thu, "h_fri": h_fri, "h_sat": h_sat });
            task_data.push({ "taskName": taskName, "task_detail_data": task_detail_data });

            var index = project_data.map(function (o) { return o.projName; }).indexOf("1");

            project_data[index].task_data.push(task_data);
        }
        
    }

    var output = { projects: project_data };
    var json = JSON.stringify(output);
    $('#output').html(json);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot krlzlx. it works like charm. i really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = [
 {
   "Id":1,
   "userId":"dd1789f1-bb28-4f2c-975a-bad0e3d127cd",
   "email":"lalaland@gmail.com",
   "projName":"1",
   "taskName":"2",
   "startDate":"2017-01-22",
   "endDate":"2017-01-28",
   "hr_Sun":"0.00",
   "hr_Mon":"0.00",
   "hr_Tue":"0.00",
   "hr_Wed":"0.00",
   "hr_Thu":"0.00",
   "hr_Fri":"0.00",
   "hr_Sat":"0.00",
   "total_hr":"0.00"
 },
 {
   "Id":2,
   "userId":"dd1789f1-bb28-4f2c-975a-bad0e3d127cd",
   "email":"lalaland@gmail.com",
   "projName":"1",
   "taskName":"3",
   "startDate":"2017-01-22",
   "endDate":"2017-01-28",
   "hr_Sun":"0.00",
   "hr_Mon":"0.00",
   "hr_Tue":"0.00",
   "hr_Wed":"0.00",
   "hr_Thu":"0.00",
   "hr_Fri":"0.00",
   "hr_Sat":"0.00",
   "total_hr":"0.00"
 },
 {
   "Id":3,
   "userId":"dd1789f1-bb28-4f2c-975a-bad0e3d127cd",
   "email":"lalaland@gmail.com",
   "projName":"2",
   "taskName":"3",
   "startDate":"2017-01-22",
   "endDate":"2017-01-28",
   "hr_Sun":"0.00",
   "hr_Mon":"0.00",
   "hr_Tue":"0.00",
   "hr_Wed":"0.00",
   "hr_Thu":"0.00",
   "hr_Fri":"0.00",
   "hr_Sat":"0.00",
   "total_hr":"0.00"
 }
];

// an array of hDays combo so we won't have to set each one manually
var hDays = ["hr_Sun", "hr_Mon", "hr_Tue", "hr_Wed", "hr_Thu", "hr_Fri", "hr_Sat"];

// get the task_data of an item
function getTaskData(item){
    var obj = {}; // the task_data placeholder
    obj["taskName"] = item["taskName"]; // set the name of this task_data
    
    var tdd = {}; // task_detail_data placeholder
    hDays.forEach(function(hday){ // automate the assignments using the above array (or write 8 lines of code assigning them manually)
        tdd[hday] = item[hday]; // tdd and item will have the same keys (your question says tdd should have keys like 'h_sun', 'h_mon'... and not like the original keys ('hr_Sun', 'hr_Mon'...) which I assumed it was an orthograph error. If my assumption is not right, some changes here are required)
    });
    // I don't know why you want this to be an array that contain only one object.
    obj["task_detail_data"] = [tdd];
    
    return obj;
}

// Accumulate the result while looping through the items of 'data'
var result = data.reduce(function(acc, item){
    // Check we already stored element with projName equal to this item projName
    var found = acc.find(function(e){
        return e["projName"] == item["projName"];
    });
    // If we already have, then get this item task_data and push it into the array of task_data of this projName
    if(found)
        found["task_data"].push(getTaskData(item));
    // If not, then push an element having this projName
    else{
        acc.push({
            "projName": item["projName"],
            "task_data": [getTaskData(item)] // must be an array so we can push to it further task_data if ever we encounter an item with the same projName
        });
    }
    
    return acc; // return the accumulator
}, []);

//result is an array of projects. If you want the format in the question use this (although I don't see the reason why):
var theCorrectResult = {
    "projects": result
};

console.log(theCorrectResult);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable comments on each code to help understand this code. :)